# save an image (from a url) to the java code location

Tags: java

i want to save an image (from a url) to my disk by the below code.
i want the code save this image in the location of java code. for example, if the source java code is in D:\example\saveimage.java, this image saves in D:\example\image.jpg. this location may be changed in the install process.
how can i do this? what is its java code?
thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String imageUrl ="http://imgs.yooz.ir/yooz/walls/yooz-950625.jpg";

    String destinationFile = "E:\\Picture\\Wallpaper.jpg";
    //destinationFile =  location of the source java code

    saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
}

public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    try {
        InputStream is=url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ImageIO.read(URL)`, `ImageIO.write(File)`...*" want the code save this image in the location of java code"* - Okay, that's harder, you could save it within the current execution context or "working directory" of the program using `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: very thanks MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String destinationFile = "E:\\Picture\\Wallpaper.jpg";
```

this is a straight addressing. you can use relative addressing

for example here use:

```
String destinationFile = "Wallpaper.jpg";
```

just saves image in Wallpaper.jpg and in the same folder as java file

Comment: very thanks Reza. i want to use this image in another class. maybe help me: how can i address to this image? or how can i use this image?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. save the file in the current directory, or to a path relative to current directory
2. have the path of the directory in a properties file, the properties file being in the classpath
3. define a system property
4. pass the path as an argument
5. etc...